# Show that this polynomial in two variables has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, roots, quadratics

> Consider the equation $15x^2 - 7y^2 = 16$.  Show that it has no integer solutions.

Any hints or comments are welcome.

Comment: How do you know that this is something you can contradict? Perhaps there is a §§15x^2 - 7y^2§§ with §§x,y \in \mathbb{Z}§§,  that is divisible by 16, but not 16 itself. I am just asking, I probably don't have enough background knowledge here.

Comment: @MartinErhardt. If 4|x and 4|y...............

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint : Considering in mod $m$ for some $m\ge 2\in\mathbb N$ sometimes works. In our case, $m=3$.

---

**Added** : It seems that you are not familiar with considering in mod $m$.

The equation can be written as
$$y^2=3(5x^2-2y^2-6)+2$$
So, $y^2$ has to be of the form $3k+2$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. This is impossible. (why?)

Comment: Hi @mathlove, assuming $x,y \in \mathbb{z}$ and using your equation, then we get $\frac{y^2}{3} - \frac{2}{3}$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks so much @mathlove.  I rewrote my work above and got the residues 0, 1 or 0, and 1.  How can I use this approach?  It's my first time working in modular arithmetic.  Do the residues just replace / play the role of their respective base numbers?

Comment: @user58865: To the first comment, you need to show that $\frac{y^2}{3}-\frac 23$ is never an integer. Separating it into three cases $y=3m,y=3m+1$ or $y=3m+2$ should help. To the second, you are almost there. You get $\text{LHS}\equiv 2$ or $\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Comment: Hi @mathlove...still stuck on the very last part.  So if I plug the residues into the equation, I get contradictions and that should be it.  But I'm not sure why we can just simply look at the residues.  Like...$15x^2$ is "related" to $0$ by the congruence relation $15x^2 \equiv 0$ mod $3$, but they aren't *equal* ...is my trouble...

Comment: @user58865: OK, let me explain. First, $a\equiv b\pmod 3$ means that there exists an integer $k$ such that $a-b=3k$. Now, as you wrote, $15x^2\equiv 0\pmod 3, 7y^2\equiv 1\quad\text{or}\quad 0\pmod 3$ and $16\equiv 1\pmod 3$. So, $\text{LHS}\equiv 0-1\equiv 2\pmod 3\quad\text{or}\quad 0-0\equiv 0\pmod 3$ while $\text{RHS}\equiv 1\pmod 3$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @user58865: In other words, the LHS is of the form $3p+2$ or $3q$ while the RHS is of the form $3r+1$. This is a contradiction. You may want to see [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: Hi @mathlove, I'm getting that, since the congruence relation respects addition and subtraction then the LHS $15x^2 - 7y^2$ is congruent to -1 (mod 3)  *or* 0 (mod 3), while the RHS is congruent to 1(mod 3), which is a contradiction.  How did you get 2 (mod 3)?

Comment: I got the answer @mathlove -- thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @user58865: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation modulo 3:
$$15x^2-7y^2=16$$

- $15x^2$ is always divisible by 3,
- $7y^2$ is either 0 or 1 modulo 3 and
- $16\equiv1\pmod3$.

Substituting these residues into the equation, we find that it is inconsistent in all cases:
$$0-0\not\equiv1\pmod3$$
$$0-1\not\equiv1\pmod3$$
$$15x^2-7y^2\not\equiv16\pmod3$$
Therefore the equation has no integer solution.

Comment: It doesn't look like a hint ...

Comment: @EugenCovaci Why is it not a hint?

Comment: Hi @ParclyTaxel, how come we can just substitute the residues?

Comment: @user58865 Suppose I have an equation with integers. If I replace each integer with its residue modulo some number, the equation still holds (modulo the modulus, of course). You may want to read up on [modular arithmetic on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to find out more - this is the theory of congruences, and its applications are everywhere.

Comment: hi @ParclyTaxel, what do you think of my revised work?  now I know that congruence relations respect addition, subtraction and multiplication.  so the LHS is either congruent to 0 (mod 3) or -1(mod) 3, while the RHS is congruent to 1(mod 3), which is a contradiction.  Do you agree?  I hope I am getting the concept of adding and subtracting the congruence relations correct...

Comment: @user58865 Yes. Your working is complete and correct. Note that modulo n we can add n or subtract n and get back the same "thing"; -1 mod 3 is also 2 mod 3.

Comment: Because it is  a complete solution

Answer (score 2):

A good learning Software for your problem was written
by [Dario Alejandro Alpern](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM):

set mode to Step-by-Step.

First of all we must determine the $gcd$ of all coefficients but the constant term, that is: $gcd(15, 0, -7, 0, 0) = 1.$

Dividing the equation by the greatest common divisor we obtain:
 $15 x^2 - 7 y^2 - 16 = 0$.

We try to check the equation modulo the prime divisors of $15$
... here the hint ends :) ...

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit long.
 Assuming x, y are integers, they can either be even or odd.
But only one of them being even and other being odd cannot be solution, since difference of odd and even numbers will not be even.

So they either have to both even or both odd.

If x and y are even then equation will be 60a-28b =16.

First term always ends in 0, second term has to end in 4. Meaning b which is a square should end in either 3 or 8, and there are no such numbers. So x cannot be even and y cannot be odd

Last possibility is x, y both are odd.

If x is odd, then first term will always end in 5. And second term has to end in 9. Meaning y square should end in 7. Since there are no such squares, x,y both cannot be odd.

Thus the equation cannot have integer solution.

It's a bit long though.